# Exiting OSMC to RBPi Terminal

Tags: linux, osmc, lxterminal

How do I exit OSMC back to the a Raspberry 
Pi terminal?I've tried the 'esc key' method,it didn't work.
I just wanna close OSMC to access the coding terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this through the Yatse remote on your smart phone or tablet.  Otherwise, if you click the power down icon at the bottom left, you should have an option to exit OSMC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate.The power option on the left doesn't work.I've tried that already.Does anyone know why it's so difficult to close OSMC?

Comment: I'll try the Yatse remote.What a mission just to close a window.

Comment: You should be able to just use a mouse

Answer (score 0):

Which skin do you have?

If you have the classic Kodi skin the power button isn't in the bottom left it's more toward the top left on the home screen. Either way when you hit it you get a pop up with "Exit" "shutdown" "reboot" and one other. Hit "Exit" then as soon as you see the Splash screen with the OSMC logo press and hold esc untill a command line comes up.

The default username is osmc and the password is the same as the username. As always you should 100% definitely change the password.

If this doesn't work enable SSH on your program through the OSMC app store and get a program called PuTTy. You'll need to know the IP of your pi but that can be found in the network info part of the settings